# How to remove chewing gum from hair

Tags: personal-care, hair

**How can I easily and effectively remove chewing gum *(or similar)* that has become stuck in a persons (*or animals)* hair?**

I am talking about hair that is at least an inch in length and commonly found on one's head.

Removal by cutting is a sort of last option so I would like to avoid this if possible! Also I would not like anything that would long term damage the hair / head / skin.

Comment: @Mooseman ah yeah I'll give you that one! I did search prior to asking - couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, but multiple people have already asked this question. Remember the golden rule of the Stack Exchange: Duplicate questions make it harder to help everyone else. Please remember to search your question to see if someone already has!

Now, on the topic of your question: Freezing the gum works incredibly well, as it will just snap off.

Regards,
Delta Escher

Comment: If you read the comments I did search - I couldn't find it so i accept that it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't read them. Did you find the answer helpful though?

Answer (score 2):

This May sound weird but you can use coca cola to remove chewing gum from your hair.

Regards

Antoine Dubuis